# InstallShield sign the code with EV code + hardware token

Tags: installshield, code-signing-certificate

We need to sign our install via InstallShield 2013 express with EV code with hardware token, however there is no way to export a private key certificate file, so the only way is to manually sign the final exe file with DigiCertUtil tool, but this is not solution because windows is still pop up unknown publisher when installer invoke the msi file, does any one solve this issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It took me a better part of a day to figure out how to achieve this, but I finally managed to make it work on a dummy project.

Setup:

- [InstallShield 2015 Premier](https://www.flexera.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/) from Flexera
- [DigiCert EV code-signing](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-code-signing/) certificate with a Gemalto Hardware key (SafeNet)
- [SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe) from Microsoft

The idea is to run batch commands from InstallShield's `Precompression` and `Postbuild` event. The *.msi* is signed in the `Precompression` event, and the setup executable is signed in the `Postbuild` event.

**Step 1 - enable batch code signature**

- Follow the instructions from Digicert [here](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-authenticode-certificates.htm). Other vendors probably have equivalent instructions.
- Make sure you extract the correct certificate Thumbprint, and use it as an argument to Signtool. I recommend you do so even if you don't have other certificates installed on your machine

**Step 2 - prepare InstallShield project**

- Under "Path Variables" add the following values:

  - SignToolFolder - path to where signtool.exe is
  - CertificateThumbprint - the certificate thumbprint extracted in step 1
- Under "Releases", choose your release, and go to the "Events" tab.
- In *Precompression Event* write (replace Test.msi and the path with your msi's name and path):
  `cmd /c "<SignToolFolder>\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /sha1 <CertificateThumbprint> <ISReleasePath>\<ISProductConfigName>\<ISReleaseName>\DiskImages\DISK1\Test.msi`
- In *Postbuild Event* write: `cmd /c "<SignToolFolder>\signtool.exe" sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /sha1 <CertificateThumbprint> <ISReleasePath>\<ISProductConfigName>\<ISReleaseName>\DiskImages\DISK1\setup.exe`. Again, change the setup.exe path and name for your needs

**Remarks**

- strangely enough, path variables are accessed using `<Var>`, not `%Var%` like in regular Windows command line.
- this will not work if you have to sign the contents of your installation. If needed - sign them externally before running IS
- unless you like spending endless hours fighting crappy software, **do not include spaces in your project name/path**
- Signing will only work if you physically log into the machine. Remote sessions (RDP, VNC, etc.) **will not work**
- switch to Wix :)

Comment: Works well, some notes: it uses `<>` syntax because it's Installshield which does the substitution, not cmd; running via `cmd /c` is not needed; seems the postbuild event runs after copying setup.exe to the destination path (if 'Copy to Foler' is used) so in that case you need to sign the copy.

Comment: I like the last comment, switch to Wix.  Really need to do this myself at some point as Installshield express is no more but a pain to swap over.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is still the top search result, I'll add an answer for InstallShield 2022+ and a DigiCert cert with their SafeNet USB token.  It's now surprisingly simple.

Make sure your USB token is attached to the PC.

If you don't want to keep getting password popups, you can turn on "batch signing" by going to the SafeNet tools > Advanced View (gear icon) > Client Settings  > Advanced > Enable Single Login + Enable for PKCS, to only answer one password prompt until the next time you restart the PC.

**For both InstallScript EXE and Basic MSI projects**

Go to Releases > (your release) > Signing > Digital Certificate Information, click on the [...] settings button, Use a Certificate Store, choose Personal for the store name, User for the location, (Your company) for Certificate Store and IS20xx should fill in the thumbprint information for you.

**InstallScript EXE project**

Build then check that Setup.exe in the Disk 1 folder and if a self-extractor was used the .exe in Packages both have valid digital signatures.

**Basic MSI project**

Build then check the MSI

**MSIX and InstallScript MSI**

I have not used MSIX or InstallScript MSI, but the signing change are probably the same.

Comment: I also found that it will indeed sign both the setup.exe (if that is what your building) as well as the internal .msi it creates as long as you select "Setup.exe and Windows Installer Package" next to Sign Output Files on the Signing tab.

Answer (score 0):

After some headaches I got this working with InstallShield Express 2018 so am adding the details for those doing the same (and for myself when I inevitably forget!) .  Firstly, you must do all this on the PC with the USB key attached, it won't work over remote desktop.

- Install Safenet Authentication Client, https://sectigo.com/knowledge-base/product/SafeNet_Authentication_Client_software
- Go to **SafeNET Authentication Client / Tools / Settings** Then find your certificate, right click on it and export it to a .CER file
- From Windows explorer double click on your .CER file to import it onto your PC.  Click the option to **Install Certificate...** pick **Current User** as the Store Location and **Automatically select the certificate store based on type of certificate**
- In Installshield Express go to releases, select your release and go to the signing tab
- Under **Signing / Digital certificate information** pick the ... options button
- Pick **Use a certificate store**.  For certificate store name pick personal, Certificate store location pick User, Certificate subject pick your certificate, Signature digest pick Based on certificate hash
- Build your installation, you will be prompted for the certificate password a few times so useful to have it in a paste buffer

I'm guessing many other combinations of store and certificate location would work here, the above are just what I ended up picking.

**Edit:** TeamViewer lets you do this remotely with USB key plugged into remote PC.